# Rails 4 grouped_collection_select with scopes for ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, formbuilder

I used to have this code working in Rails 3.2.16:

```
f.grouped_collection_select :state_id, @states.ordered, 'children.ordered', :name, :id, :name
```

After upgrading to Rails 4.0 I receive the error:

```
undefined method `children.ordered' for #<State:0x007f66498d90f8>
```

This seems to have something to do with the fact that scopes are only allowed as callables. My model looks like this:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: 'State', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'State'

  scope :ordered, -> {
    order(:sequence)
       .order(:name)
  }
end
```

Anybody know how to make this work again? I'm not able to use default_scope here, because it would require a lot of place to override this default scope.

Comment: No, I've made a function that retuns the children as ordered, so the function combines the two scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by create a function `children_ordered` which combines both scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You might have found the answer to this question already. But I think you should change the code with the grouped_collection_select helper to call the group_method:

`f.grouped_collection_select :state_id, @states.ordered, :children, :name, :id, :name`

From the Rails 4 documentation:

`grouped_collection_select(object, method, collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

**Update:**

I was to fast to answer and you are correct. You might need to use `default_scope` to get it to work the way you want?

Comment: How is your answer ordering the children? The problem was that it's not possible anymore to use the :ordered scope.

Comment: See my update, might not help you. I will keep investigate this more. Strange that you can't use scope anymore with grouped_colelction_select.

Comment: See the original post: "I'm not able to use default_scope here, because it would require a lot of place to override this default scope."